# Printing out high scores in a list

Tags: python, pygame, livewires

So in my menu for my game I want to be able to print out the high scores from a .txt file line by line, but with my current code it just adds all the scores to one line could someone please help?, I am using Livewires and Pygame.

```
    def highscores(self):

        sf = open('highscore.txt', 'r')
        highscores = sf.readlines()
        sf.close()

        thescores = games.Text(value = highscores, size = 32, color = color.green,
                   top = 130, right = 320)

        games.screen.add(thescores)
```

Answer (score 2):

`highscores` is a list, so you need to loop over it:

```
def highscores(self):

        sf = open('highscore.txt', 'r')
        highscores = sf.readlines()
        sf.close()
        top = 130

        for highscore in highscores:
            thescores = games.Text(value = highscore, size = 32, color = color.green,
            top = top+10, right = 320)
            games.screen.add(thescores)
```

Comment: I was about to writing the same answer. Note that you should adjust the `top` value for each line, otherwise all text lines will be drawn above each other.

Comment: This still prints out the same as before, apart from now the printed out high scores have brackets around them which tells me there in a list. It's probably something wrong with the Livewires library

Comment: Also, `value = highscores` should be `value = highscore`

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry i just able to fix it now.